# convert interval to hours in monthly tables

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, epoch

I have 12 monthly tables, one for each month of the year 2019, records are order by an identifier (mmsi) and datetime (timestamp). I have calculated the interval (linetime2) between two consecutive rows. see below (August 2019):

[image]

Now I need to convert interval in hours in a new column. How can I do it? Can I run this:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(epoch FROM linetime2)/3600
```

or I have to take into account the number of days in a month and year?

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: The query looks fine. Did you get an error? Wrong results?

Comment: I will format the table according to your recomendation next time, thank you. the query is ok but I have read in another post that 'simply extracting epoch implicitly assumes that one month = 30 days and one year = 365.25 days'

Comment: If the interval is the result of subtracting a timestamptz from another timestamptz it will have taken any month/year borders (including leap months or DST changes) into account. You will have a duration that is applicable for the given start and end date/time.

Comment: Using a window function I have calculated for the datetime column (timestamp without time zone) the interval between row 2 and row 1, row 3 and row 2 and so on. should be ok?

Comment: Should be OK, yes

Comment: Thank you, the window functions are very useful! I would like to learn more about it